# Retrofit 2.0 Convertor returns NULL

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, callback, retrofit

I use **Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2**.

I found an [example](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/5d249a397a571421dc1fd8573f9f80bf2ee3a81d/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/DeserializeErrorBody.java) of a **synchronous** conversion **.errorBody** to object.

I need to implement it asynchronously.

It's my json:

```
{
  "error_msg": "This user name is already registered."
}
```

When run the **asynchronous** example, I get ***null***.

```
package com.test.client;

import com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.Converter;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public final class DeserializeErrorBody {

interface Service {
    @GET("account.signup")
    Call<User> getUser();
}

static class User {
    // normal fields...
}

static class Error {
    String error_msg;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.site.com/method/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);


    // ASYNCHRONOUS

    Call<User> response = service.getUser();
    response.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if(!responce.isSuccess()) {

                System.out.println(response.errorBody().string()); // returns { "error_msg": "This user name is already registered."}    :)))))

                Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter = retrofit.responseConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);

                try {
                    Error error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());

                    System.out.println(error); // returns null   :((((((

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // ...
        }
    });


    // SYNCHRONOUS

    /*
    Response<User> call = service.getUser().execute();
    Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter = retrofit.responseConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);

    Error error = errorConverter.convert(call.errorBody());
    System.out.println(error); // returns Object     :))))))
    System.out.println(error.error_msg); // returns "This user name is already registered."    :))))))
    */

}
}
```

Sorry for my bad English :)

In asynchronous request **successfully returns a string**. However, conversion to the **object** is **not** running.

How to get the **object** instead of ***null***?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get the object instead of null?

Comment: Your method  **Call<User> getUser();** is synchronous for asynchronous request check [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests/) link

Comment: @NullPointerException,
Your article uses version **retrofit 1.9**.
In version **2.0**, the interface is described by the same for synchronous and asynchronous requests.
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so your problem lies within following line of code:

`System.out.println(response.errorBody().string());`

If you take a look on the source of [com.squareapp.okhttp.ResponseBody](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody.java#L83) you will find out that call to `string()` will consume out the stream of response. So the next time you are trying to parse body of response

`Error error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());`

Call to `errorBody()` will give no stream of bytes and Gson won't parse any data back.

So what should you try? Just don't consume `errorBody()` in the way you did. Simply remove this line:

`System.out.println(response.errorBody().string());`

If you need advanced logging [follow link](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor). This should essentially look like this:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(Level.BASIC);
client.interceptors().add(logging);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("https://api.site.com/method/")
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
       .client(client)
       .build();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is working! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can somebody please advise? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261481/assigning-reference-when-accessing-json-response